# Passing Own object into navigation Windows Phone 7 (silverlight)

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, navigation

I have my own object and I need to view a list of that object on another windows phone page. This is the code I have so far to navigate to my other page. I need to list the the list of car owners in a listbox on the other page

```
        private void btnOwners_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
             NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri
                    ("/ViewCarMembers.xaml?info=" + 
                      currentCar.Owners, UriKind.Relative));
        }
```

currentCar.Owners is basically List of that specified car(which of of type Car)

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is another way do pass your object to/from the page.
I noticed this trick from wp7 toolkit. DatePicker control works the same.
Here is the trick.

You can obtain root frame by using:

```
var frame = Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame
```

Then you can navigate to another page by using:

```
frame.Navigate(someUri)
```

And the key moment is to register your handler for frame.Navigated:

```
frame.Navigated += OnFrameNavigated;
```

And then you can pass any value to your navigated page like that:

```
private void OnFrameNavigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        var myPage = e.Content as IMyPage;
        myPage.MyObject = new MyObject();
    }
```

It's simple!

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass an object via the NavigationService.Navigate in that way, it behaves like a URL.

You need to add to the query string the information you need, read it in the OnNavigatedTo function and use the values to generate the data you need:

```
private void btnOwners_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{ 
      NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/ViewCarMembers.xaml?owners=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9",UriKind.Relative)); 
}
```

The in the page you are navigating to:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e) 
{ 
    var data = this.NavigationContext.QueryString; 

    if (data.ContainsKey("owners"))
    {
       //Iterate through values (comma seperated)
       //Populate a new list with the owners.
    }

    base.OnNavigatedTo(e); 
}
```

The above code hasn't been tested, it's just something i've made up to get the point across - you could always iterate through your list and append to the query string the full data set, pushing it back into an object on the other side.

For a better example look at how Shai Raiten does it with the following blog post:

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shair/archive/2011/05/01/wp7-data-between-pages-part-1.aspx

Comment: in your first section of code, can you explain the numbers a little better please

Comment: The numbers were just an example of a unique reference (or id). If your collection had a property that was unique you can use that instead. This allows you to get the value when you navigate to the next page and construct the list as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

One way to make this work would be to create a `ToCSV()` function that takes a `List<String>` and converts it to a single string where the values in the list are separated by commas. You could then call it as follows:

```
private void btnOwners_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri
    ("/ViewCarMembers.xaml?info=" + 
      ToCSV( currentCar.Owners ), UriKind.Relative));
}
```

The `ToCSV()` function will need to call [`Uri.EscapeDataString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapedatastring%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) on every owner name before apeending it to the output string to insert the appropriate escape characters; the string is automatically unescaped, so don't need to do anything within the `ViewCarMembers` page. You'll also need to create a function to parse the CSV list and use it on the destination page.

A better solution would be to pass the name of the specified car instead of the names of all its owners, then have the destination page fetch the list of owners from the ViewModel.

Comment: how do I do the better solution

Comment: He doesn't seem to specify that he's using MVVM.

Comment: @user1290653 Try mine as an example if you're interested in Prætorian 's other solution.

Comment: whats that, never heard of it, im new to this

Comment: @user1290653 Be aware, if you were to use the ToCSV option the URI string cannot exceed a certain length - MSDN says 65519 characters is the maximum (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6c2z492.aspx)

Comment: @user1290653 There must be some place in your app where you keep a list of all cars and lists of owners of each of those cars, right? Just make that data structure accessible to the destination page, pass the name of the car from the originating page, and then the destination can go look up the list of owners from the data structure.

Comment: thats what i figured I could do but its hurting my head as to how

Comment: @user1290653 Make the data structure a public member of the `App` class, now it is available to your entire application.

Comment: how does it know which car to look at

Comment: @user1290653 `currentCar` is the car to look at, isn't it? Just pass the name of that car in the query string instead of the list of owners. Then have the `ViewCarMembers` page find that car and its list of owners as I explained in the comments above. I've edited the example code, realized the earlier version was wrong.